Google Slides App Script remove() function stopped working?
UPDATE: A Google slides presentation with more than 1 slide, with any slide having more than 1 animation on it causes the first use of the remove() or move(index) function to fail with an Unexpected error.
I have a Google App Script which takes a Sheets spreadsheet and uses it to create a Slides slideshow from a saved template in Drive. This script has run on two to three Sheets per day flawlessly for probably a year or two with no recent change to the code or template Slides slideshow.
On Tues, Aug 20th 2024 it started failing on the remove() function with Unexpected error while getting the method or property remove on object SlidesApp.Slide.
Using app script I can change text, change image references and set slides to be skipped/hidden.  remove() and move(index) so far are all I've come across which throw this error, and only if the slideshow has more than 1 slide AND 1 or more slides have more than 1 animation on it. If you have a Slides presentation with no animations (or just 1 per slide max) it works as expected.
Here is a repro video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ehw3vp83Z_CBpPguRdZoyLMHVVTWVH9r/
function moveEveryOddSlideToBeginning() {
  //slideshow : https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1nO5w6ZXRUlKMg8MY2A5gqO6Wewa4Kl-RWimDQ4nGRTU
  var presentationId = "1nO5w6ZXRUlKMg8MY2A5gqO6Wewa4Kl-RWimDQ4nGRTU";
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  var count = 0;

  slides.forEach(function(slide, index) {
    count++;
    console.log(count);
    if (count % 2 == 1)
    {
      console.log("moving");
      slide.move(0);
    }
  });
}



About this script (unchanged for quite a while) started failing on the remove(), I think that your showing script, slide.remove(); works. And, I cannot understand the situation The Slides file can be modified by the script but I cannot remove a slide nor move a slide, however I can mark it as skipped.. In this case, in order to correctly replicating your situation, can you provide a sample Google Slide?

A few days ago, a question about the same issue / error message was posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAppsScript/ and answered by the OP

I think I found a solution in my specific case
After writing a bunch of simplified scripts and testing all kinds of presentation I narrowed down the issue to the biggest ones
Through trial and error I came to the conclusion that they might be just too heavy for the api, so I wrote a function using getThumbnailUrl() to replace all videos with images
That did the trick, maybe it could help you as well 


it has SOMETHING to do with animations. I've managed to run my stripped down remove code block by using a Slideshow that doesn't have any animation in it, but that just makes NO sense. Why wouldn't you be able to remove a slide because your presentation has an animation in it somewhere else?

Thanks for sharing your findings. Still there are not enough details, however, looking at the animation might be a good hint for other having the same problem.

I've boiled this issue down to the base case. If a slideshow has at least 2 slides in it and a slide anywhere in that slideshow has more than 1 animation on it, remove() and move(index) no longer works with an unidentified error.  This started a few days ago
Have a repro video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ehw3vp83Z_CBpPguRdZoyLMHVVTWVH9r/view?usp=sharing
I fail to see any reason why this would work short of a bug in the Google App Script framework at this point.  My main script run multiple times per day, this stopped working on Tuesday Aug 20.
